# Federated Authentication Session Authentication Module Add Claim MVC 5

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, token, federated-identity

I have a need to add claims to a cookie after logging in to a 3rd party system. I somewhat get how FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule works but I'm not 100%. I know that you have to add the following to the web config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"></add>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

I also know that you have to add references for System.IdentityModel and System.IdentityModel.Services

In the Home Controller for the Index method I send the request for the third party cookie with the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(string projectId, int companyId, bool isCompanyAdmin)
{
    if (!_isTesting)
    {
        // if not a valid user return error
        var validate = new Validate().ValidateContext(HttpContext,
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.FlexClientKey],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.FlexClientSecret]);
        if (!validate.IsValidated) return View(Constants.ValidationFailed);
    }

    // Add claims here

    return View();
}
```

I currently have it so that where the //Add claims here is is the following code:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(ci);
var token = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
    cp, 
    "BatchSMS",
    DateTime.UtcNow, 
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), 
    true);

FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);
```

However I'm getting an Access is denied error. I don't know if I'm even close to doing this right. Am I supposed to be adding some sort of class implementing an interface and calling that? What am I missing?